# How to upload video on jwplayer using php script?

Tags: jwplayer

I was going through jwPlayer api and I found ways in which it provides plugin to get upload form so that my users can directly upload their video to my jwPlayer account.
But I require some other service. Actually I already have list of videos in a folder and also its list is maintained in a database (by some background process). And, I want to upload it on jwPlayer using some (php) script so that at the end of each day when I have received all new videos for that day (by that background process), I can run that (php) script to get all those new videos uploaded on jwPlayer.

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. It sounds like you're either asking for somebody to write a PHP script for you, or like you're looking for a recommendation for a tool to do this stuff for you. You should be aware that bother of these requests are generally off-topic on SO. SO is generally for fixing problems in code and coding tools. Now, if you have a PHP script that you need help with, by all means post that. But this question now, as it stands, is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 3):

Use the PHP API adapter: https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplatform-php

Example:

```
$jwplatform_api = new Jwplayer\JwplatformAPI('INSERT API KEY', 'INSERT API SECRET');

$target_file = 'YOUR_VIDEO.mp4';
$params = array();
$params['title'] = 'PHP API Test Upload';
$params['description'] = 'Video description here';

// Create the example video
$create_response = json_encode($jwplatform_api->call('/videos/create', $params));    
$decoded = json_decode(trim($create_response), TRUE);
$upload_link = $decoded['link'];

$upload_response = $jwplatform_api->upload($upload_link, $target_file);

print_r($upload_response);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a JW Player account that has an API key and secret (for video uploads), you can use our API to do this:

http://apidocs.jwplayer.com/

Here is some more reference:

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1489902-jw-platform-api-reference

On this page is a download link to some PHP API Examples, in a Zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP API adapter: https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplatform-php

example:

```
<?php

// require_once('./init.php'); require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

// set these environment variables $secret =
$_ENV['JWPLATFORM_API_SECRET']; $site_id =
$_ENV['JWPLATFORM_SITE_ID'];

$jwplatform_api = new Jwplayer\JwplatformClient($secret);

$target_file = 'examples/test.mp4'; $params = array();
$params['metadata'] = array(); $params['metadata']['title'] = 'PHP
API Test Upload'; $params['metadata']['description'] = 'Video
description here'; $params['upload'] = array();
$params['upload']['method'] = 'direct';


// Create the example media $create_response =
json_encode($jwplatform_api->Media->create($site_id, $params));

print_r($create_response); print("\n");

$decoded = json_decode(json_decode(trim($create_response), true),
true); $upload_link = $decoded['upload_link'];

// Upload the media file $upload_response =
$jwplatform_api->Media->upload($target_file, $upload_link);

print_r($upload_response); print("\n");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that Kamil Sindi uses v1 of the API which JWPlayer will deprecate in June 2023.
Vivek krish's answer uses v2, but for a "Direct Single Upload" which is the simplest way to get a locally available, smaller (<100MB).

Here is another example using PHP API adapter v2 as well https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplatform-php, but using the "Fetch upload via URL recipe" this time, to use when the media file is already remotely hosted elsewhere (for example in Dropbox, Google, or Amazon). That works with files up to 5Gb.

```
$params = [
  'upload' => [
    'method' => 'fetch',
    'download_url' => 'YOUR_REMOTE_URL'
  ],
  'metadata' => [
    'title' => 'YOUR_MEDIA_TITLE',
    'description' => 'YOUR_MEDIA_DESCRIPTION',
  ]
];
// With v2, you need to go to API Credentials, and at the bottom of the page, you can create new API KEY
// that will have a Role and a group of properties it can access
// This new API KEY will only have a secret (no ID)
$jwplatform_client = new \Jwplayer\JwplatformClient("YOUR_CREDENTIAL_V2_PROPERTY_GROUP_SECRET");
$create_response = json_encode($jwplatform_client->Media->create('ID_OF_PROPERTY_TO_UPLOAD_TO', $params));
$response = json_decode(json_decode(trim($create_response), true), true);

if (isset($response['errors'])) {
  $error_code = $response['errors'][0]['code'];
  $description = $response['errors'][0]['description'];
  throw new \Exception("JW Player Error at media creation : " . $error_code . " : " . $description);
}

if (isset($response['id']) && !empty($response['id'])) {
  $entity->storeJWMediaID($response['id']);
}
else {
  throw new \Exception("No JWPlayer ID returned after upload");
}
```